# How can I count names and insert it as a column in SQL?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite which has two columns (name and age). Something like this:

Ann   29
John  30
Mark  14
Ann   18
Brian 45
Brian 21
Brian 19

I would like to add a third column to this table and show how many times this name is repeated (I don't care about the age). Something like this:

Ann   29  2
John  30  1
Mark  14  1
Ann   18  2
Brian 45  3
Brian 21  3
Brian 19  3

How can I do it in SQL (SQLite)?

Comment: When you post a question like this, try first and include what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a select sql example counting repeated name likes this:

```
SELECT name, age, (SELECT count(*) FROM tableName t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name) as repeated
FROM tableName t1
```

Or add a new column and use update sql to count repeated name:

```
UPDATE tableName t1
SET repeated = (SELECT count(*) FROM tableName t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE : Don't read it if you are looking for cooked up code.

Its a three step process since you already have a table populated with data else just follow the third step.

1. First modify the table structure with default value 1.
2. Then run a update query on the table and update the value of the count column (Hint : Try to use count() function that will help).
3. When you are inserting new columns, create a trigger for counting the values and updating count for that entry automatically after insertion.

Answer (score 1):

You can query a table which is joined from the existing and one made on the fly with names and their count:

```
select *
from names 
left join
 (select name, count(name)
  from names
  group by name)
using(name);
```

Output (I have one typo in the age value of one of the Anns):

```
Ann|29|2
John|30|1
Mark|14|1
Ann|29|2
Brian|45|3
Brian|21|3
Brian|19|3
```

MCVE:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE names (name varchar(10), age int);
INSERT INTO names VALUES('Ann',29);
INSERT INTO names VALUES('John',30);
INSERT INTO names VALUES('Mark',14);
INSERT INTO names VALUES('Ann',29);
INSERT INTO names VALUES('Brian',45);
INSERT INTO names VALUES('Brian',21);
INSERT INTO names VALUES('Brian',19);
COMMIT;
```